# Cannot figure out why this is not working

Tags: javascript, src

I cannot figure out, that in mobile view, why my hamburger menu onclick function is not working.

```
var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", changeImage);

function changeImage() {
    if (hamburger.src === "./images/icon-hamburger.svg") {
        hamburger.src = "./images/icon-close.svg";
        document.getElementById("hidden-nav").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        hamburger.src = "./images/icon-hamburger.svg";
        document.getElementById("hidden-nav").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I dont know if you need any other information to help me, but this is making me a bit anxious, because I feel like the code should be working, but it actually does **nothing**.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Any console errors? Did you check if the listener is running to start with?

Comment: No, i have nothing.
"Did you check if the listener is running to start with" - i dont really understand this

Comment: does that mean there's nothing in the developer tools console, or you haven't looked at the developer tools console?

Comment: There is actually nothing in the console. I also logged the hamburger.src , and it gives me the proper source which is given in HTML.

Comment: Insert `console.log(hamburger);` line right after `var hamburger = ...` and check if this code is actually running and printing to console

Comment: you log in the `hamburger.src` in `changeIamage` or outside ?

Comment: For console.log(hamburger); i  get the following (even when i place it right behind the var hamburger = ...): <img id="hamburger" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="">

Comment: I log it outside of changeImage

Comment: I'll give you little bit different solution, try this : `var mnu = document.getElementById('hidden-nav'); if(mnu.style.display=='' || mnu.style.display='block') { /*do what you need, change src to hamburger-icon*/} else {/* change src to close-icon*/}`.

Comment: It seems like the function is not working for some reason, because when I try to console.log(hamburger) in the function. I dont even get the log into console.

Comment: can you post some result about `var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");` log it before you add eventListener

Comment: console.log(hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger"));
 --> <img id="hamburger" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="">

Comment: @LajosDuzmath I think you should prepare a JSFiddle example of your problem. There are not enough details for answering your question, just suggestions.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mROFxmPxbe

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure css to change hamburger style instead of using images.

I have added a hamburger and a sidebar functionality below.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var y = document.getElementById("ham");
  if (y.className == "container change") {
   y.classList.remove("change");
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
  else {
  y.classList.add("change");
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }
  
}
```

```css
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}


/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<p>Click on the Menu Icon to transform it to "X":</p>
<div class="container" id="ham" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kal. But I am trying to solve it with JS, to practice JS.:)

Comment: I am using JS too. Please take a look at the code. The only difference is that I am not using images for the hamburger. The hamburger is toggled with this one line of JS - `x.classList.toggle("change")`

Answer (score 0):

I can figure out 2 situations, first you load your `javascript` file( or just in html script) in `<head>` tag, that cause its loaded before your page fully loaded. this is could cause `document.getElementById("hamburger")` didn't find anything. to avoid this you have to push your scripts in the end of html and make sure that its fire after page loaded all components like so

```
var hamburger;
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger")
    hamburger.addEventListener("click", changeImage);
});

function changeImage() {
    if (hamburger.src === "./images/icon-hamburger.svg") {
        hamburger.src = "./images/icon-close.svg";
        document.getElementById("hidden-nav").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        hamburger.src = "./images/icon-hamburger.svg";
        document.getElementById("hidden-nav").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

another possible mistake is in your layering html! make sure the element you add the event listener to it is in top in dom layers. make sure your hamburger element is in top layer with `z-index`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have to leave for work, but sure will check the z-indexes in the afternoon because it seems to be a logical issue.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the issue, it works totally fine with the following code:

```
var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
var hiddenNav = document.getElementById("hidden-nav");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", changeImage);


function changeImage() {
    if (hiddenNav.style.display === "none") {
        hamburger.src = "./images/icon-close.svg";
        hiddenNav.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        hamburger.src = "./images/icon-hamburger.svg";
        hiddenNav.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Not sure why and how this is functioning perfectly and the other is not, but it's solved and this is what matters.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.